# While stored procedure how to take values from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure like this

```
SELECT t.transactID, 
       t.TBarcode, 
       t.PAICID, 
       t.Status, 
       k.HBarcode, 
       ISNULL(COALESCE(u.uname, e.Ename), 'Deliver') AS EName 
FROM   
    Transaction_tbl 
LEFT JOIN 
    UserMaster_tbl u ON u.ECode = t.Ecode AND t.Status = 0 
LEFT JOIN 
    EmployeeMaster_tbl e ON e.ECode = t.ECode AND t.Status = 1 OR e.Ecode = t.DelEcode AND t.Status = 4 
LEFT JOIN 
    KHanger_tbl k ON t.transactID = k.transactid AND t.Status = 2 
WHERE  
    t.TBarcode = @Carid
```

I have transaction table like this

```
transactID  TBarcode   Ecode    DelEcode     PAICID  status
1            1234       E001        E002         1         0
2             4567      E002        E001         2         1
3            24567      E003        E003         2         4
```

I have user master table

```
uid   Ecode uname
1      E001  jas
2      E002  ramu
```

I have Employeemaster table

```
Ecode   Ename
E001    jaseem
E002    ramesh
```

Uid and PAICID same

if the status =0 then  take uid of  corresponding PAICID ,then take Ecode of corresponding uid, and show then Ename from Employee master table, how I can write stored procedure of this?

Comment: Your `EName` field (before the FROM) can be re-written as `COALESCE(u.uname, e.Ename, 'Deliver')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [stored procedure if condition and taking value from multiple table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242666/stored-procedure-if-condition-and-taking-value-from-multiple-table)

Comment: Please **stop** opening more and more questions. You're allowed to *edit* your question. If the answers you get don't work, please leave *comments* to those answers saying what's wrong. Or if people misunderstand your problem, add more explanation to your *existing* question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Ename
FROM transaction
INNER JOIN master ON master.Ecode = transaction.Ecode
INNER JOIN Employeemaster ON Employeemaster.Ecode = master.Ecode
WHERE transaction.status = 0
```

Comment: where i can put this stored procedure in my stored procedur

Comment: i am new in stored procedure,,if u dont mind,,,can u please in-coperate your stored procedure to my stored procedure,,,

Comment: first i want to check paicid and uid of usermaste,,then only i want take coresponding Ecode from user master table